# Pesquisa de custom fields e tags no Wordpress com demora de resultados

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

Tenho um site em Wordpress que comporta custom fields relacionados a "Albuns de Fotografias", que agora estou criando um mecanismo de busca para tal.

O problema é que por ele utilizar Tags em seus albuns e custom_fields nas fotos, quando efetuo uma busca onde toda a pesquisa deve estar entre um, outro ou ambos, a demora de busca pelos resultados varia de 30 a 40 segundos.

Tabelas: 
wp_terms com 688 registros
wp_term_taxonomy com 752 registros
wp_term_realtionships com 4511 registros
wp_postmeta com 629459 registros
wp_post com 9929 registros

Gostaria de ajuda para otimizar esta minha subquery, que nela ocorre a demora no retorno.

```
SELECT
        t1.post_id,
        t1.meta_value,
        t1.meta_id,
        CONCAT(
            t1.meta_value,
            GROUP_CONCAT(wt. NAME SEPARATOR ',')
        ) AS conc_value,
        REPLACE (
            t1.meta_key,
            'image',
            'details'
        ) AS details,
        REPLACE (
            t1.meta_key,
            'type',
            'details'
        ) AS details2,
        REPLACE (
            t1.meta_key,
            'details',
            'image'
        ) AS details3,
        REPLACE (t1.meta_key, 'image', 'type') AS type,
        REPLACE (
            t1.meta_key,
            'details',
            'type'
        ) AS type2,
        REPLACE (t1.meta_key, 'type', 'image') AS type3
    FROM
        wp_postmeta t1
    INNER JOIN wp_posts t2 ON t1.post_id = t2.ID
    AND t2.post_type = 'post'
    INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships wtr ON t2.id = wtr.object_id
    INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy wtt ON wtt.term_taxonomy_id = wtr.term_taxonomy_id
    AND wtt.taxonomy = 'post_tag'
    INNER JOIN wp_terms wt ON wt.term_id = wtt.term_id
    GROUP BY
        t1.meta_id
    HAVING /*OS CAMPOS AQUI SÃO VARIAVEIS, ESTE CONTEM 3 POREM NO MEU CODIGO PHP EU PERMITO ATE 6 POR CONTA DA REGRA DE NEGOCIO ESTABELECIDA*/
        (
            (
                BINARY CONVERT (
                    UCASE(conc_value) USING utf8
                ) LIKE BINARY UCASE(_utf8 '%religião%')
            )
            AND
            (
                BINARY CONVERT (
                    UCASE(conc_value) USING utf8
                ) LIKE BINARY UCASE(_utf8 '%pontos%')
            )
            AND(
                BINARY CONVERT (
                    UCASE(conc_value) USING utf8
                ) LIKE BINARY UCASE(_utf8 '%centro%')
            )
            AND(
                BINARY CONVERT (
                    UCASE(conc_value) USING utf8
                ) LIKE BINARY UCASE(_utf8 '%corrente%')
            )

        )
```

Comment: A sua consulta claramente vai ser demorada, ela é gigante. Você pode descrever um pouco mais o problema, em termos da arquitetura do WP? Eu aprendi (do pior jeito possível), que é quase sempre possível buscar por coisas usando os próprios métodos do WP, sem interagir com o banco

Comment: Bom, como dito acima o site é um aglomerador de albuns de fotos, o post é o Álbum e dentro dele insiro as fotos, onde as descrições são custom fields.<estou editando sem querer enviei> A minha necessidade atual é de: obter as fotos que estão dentro do álbum através de uma pesquisa que irá verificar se: Todos os campos inseridos estão dentro da descrição (meta_value do custom field) e/ou dentro das tags do Post detentor da foto (wp_term). Este sistema não era para ter sido feito em Wordpress, eu sei, porém como estou dando manutenção nele estou buscando a melhor solução.